# исполнение функции при активированном флажке в checkbutton tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

Мне нужно, чтобы при активированном флажке и нажатии на кнопку исполнялась какая то функция.
А при деактивированном флажке и нажатии на кнопку другая функция. Как это можно сделать?

Код с checkbutton:

```
def new_window():
    new_window = tk.Toplevel(window)
    new_window.geometry(f"700x300+500+300")
    new_window.resizable(width=False, height=False)
    new_window.title("user1")
    val = tk.StringVar()
    val.set(" ")
  
    qwerty = tk.Button(new_window, text="get", command=None)
    qwerty.place(x=2, y=30)
    checkbutton1 = tk.Checkbutton(new_window, text="что то",variable = val, onvalue =0, offvalue = 1)
    checkbutton1.place(x=2, y=16)
```

Comment: как это можно осуществить? мне нужно, чтобы при активированном флажке , при нажатии на кнопку происходила какая то функция...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()
var = BooleanVar()

def func():
    if var.get() == True:
        print("Checkbutton активирован")
    elif var.get() == False:
        print("Checkbutton НЕ активирован") 

check_btn = Checkbutton(variable=var).pack()
btn = Button(text="Button", command=func).pack()

root.mainloop()
```

Ну как-то так можно...